# How to install libraries for plugin development for Gazebo Fortress (Ignition)

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-plugin, ignition-fortress, gazebo-plugins

I'm trying to write a custom plugin for Gazebo Fortress but facing issues in setting up my development environment. I installed Gazebo Fortress using the Ubuntu binaries as instructed [here](https://gazebosim.org/docs/fortress/install_ubuntu), but it seems the include headers for gz-common are missing or the entire gz-common library is missing. See the screenshot below. How can I properly install these missing libraries for Ignition Fortress and set the include dir paths?

Note that I have already added `/usr/include/ignition/gazebo6` as an include dir in VS Code, which allows it to find headers such as `ignition/gazebo/System.hh` but not `gz/common/SingletonT.hh`. In fact, there is no `common` directory inside `/usr/include/ignition/gazebo6/gz`.

Thanks so much for your help.

[image: vscode screenshot showing missing headers error]

Comment: Please paste any code or console output as code formatted text and not as a screenshot. Screenshots are not text searchable, [amongst other things](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)....

Comment: The issue was clearly explained in text. I added the screenshot as additional info.

Comment: I understand that the path is sensitive data, and there is no need to include that, but (at least) the error should be included in the question as (code formatted) text. Other people searching for the same error will not find your question as the error can not be parsed by search engines, if it is in a screenshot. Thanks. BTW, it is great that you found and pasted a solution

Comment: Noted. I will avoid text screenshots in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to add all subfolders of `/usr/include/ignition` to the include dirs.

VS Code config:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/include/ignition/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
            "compilerArgs": []
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```